# Advise for an Excel 2003 VBA video?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I would like to learn how to copy cells from an already open excel workbook to another file.  I don't just want a code, I want a tutorial.  The problem I have is Google is only giving me forums.  Can someone suggest a good tutorial with a video?  A hyper link would help.

Comment: this seems kind of obvious, but have you tried YouTube?

Comment: yeah, all the video's that came up were basic.  None told me how to go from one file to another.  They were all, "here is how to copy from one cell to another," or, "here is how to copy from one sheet to another."  I did find one video but it was just typing and not explaining.  I would like to understand what I am doing when I am done.

Comment: it's really a fairly easy concept to get. I could write you very simple and easy code to show you as an answer, but there are surely examples just as clear and simple all over SO.

Comment: Would you be willing to give ' comments for each part?  I really just couldn't find any.  I am probably using the wrong wording though.

Comment: see my answer. Comment if you need more clarification, or better yet, research what you don't understand!

Comment: Could you clarify if "to another file" means to another Excel file and, if so, whether that Excel file will already be open when you want to perform the copy?

Comment: It was another excel file

Comment: People, I see that I got a hit in the votes.  I am sorry if I offended someone by asking this advise, but I didn't know where to look and I knew that someone could help me.  I noticed that I got docked but nobody actually gave me a link to a video.  I did as much reasearch as I could and never found anything.  If you are going to dock someone then please either do some research to verify that its a legit question or don't dock them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFromOpenWorkbookToAnother()

'declare variables
Dim wkbCopy as Workbook, wkbPaste as Workbook
Dim wksCopy as Worksheet, wksPaste as Worksheet
Dim rngCopy as Range

'set variables -> change the names to suit your data needs
Set wkbCopy = Workbooks("WorkbookToCopyFrom.xls")
Set wkbPaste = Workbooks("WorkbookToCopyTo.xls")
Set wksCopy = wkbCopy.Sheets("SheetToCopy")
Set wksPaste = wkbPaste.Sheets("SheetToPaste")

Set rngCopy = wksCopy.Range("A1:A10") 'adjust to whatever range you need
rngCopy.Copy wksPaste.Range("A1") 'adjust to wherever you want to paste

End Sub
```